# Element edit button should only edit "that" element, instead is updating all

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I am trying to make an edit function for a favorites bar. Editing one box is okay, but when I try to edit a different box, all the boxes that I clicked on previously gets edited as well. Here is a jsfiddle with the complete code: https://jsfiddle.net/1exrf9h8/1/

I am trying to understand why my editFavorite function is updating multiple boxes and not just one.

```
function clickEdit(input, title, url, plus, editIcon, anchorEdit, editBtn)
{
  let i = editIcon.length - 1;

  editIcon[i].addEventListener("click", function(event){
    input.style.display = "block";
    title.value = plus[i + 1].textContent;
    url.value = anchorEdit[i].href;
    console.log(i);
    console.log(anchorEdit[i]);
    editFavorite(anchorEdit[i], url, title, input, editBtn);
  });
}

function editFavorite(changed, url, title, input, editBtn)
{
  editBtn.addEventListener("click", function(){
    changed.href = url.value;
    changed.textContent = title.value;
    input.style.display = "none";
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a few problems in your logic, architecture and use of the event handler, Let's give it a shot in a more **OOP** way so you can actually make it to work and understand what is going on.

Every single favorite is an object by itself, that can *spawn* and *update* itself.

```
function favorite(newTitle, newUrl) {
  this.element = container.appendChild(document.createElement("div"));
  this.title = this.element.appendChild(document.createElement("h2"));
  this.url = this.element.appendChild(document.createElement("h2"));

    this.update = (newTitle, newUrl) => {
      this.title.textContent = newTitle;
      this.url.textContent = newUrl;
    }

    this.createButton = () => {
      button = this.element.appendChild(document.createElement("button"));
      button.append("Edit");
      button.addEventListener("click", () => {
        let titleInput = document.getElementById("title").value;
        let urlInput = document.getElementById("url").value;

        this.update(titleInput, urlInput);
      })
  }

  this.update(newTitle, newUrl);
  this.createButton();
}
```

Then let's have a simple form where we can take inputs, using the same for editing, and creating a new favorites.

```
<input id="title" type="text" name="title" placeholder="Title">
<input id="url" type="text" name="url" placeholder="Url">
<button id="submit">Create New</button>
```

Now the actual submit logic.

```
  document.getElementById("submit").addEventListener("click", () => {
    let titleInput = document.getElementById("title").value;
    let urlInput = document.getElementById("url").value;

    if (!titleInput.length || !urlInput.length) return;
    let newFavorite = new favorite(titleInput, urlInput);
    container.appendChild(newFavorite.element);
 });
```

https://jsfiddle.net/p50L27us/48/

Comment: Thank you @Leo I took your advice and modified my code a bit. Works like a charm now :)

Answer (score -1):

The problem is caused by editFavorite function. when you call editFavorite  function automatically starts  new listener. Evey click start new one.

The solution is " ,{once : true} "

```
function editFavorite(changed, url, title, input, editBtn)
{
  editBtn.addEventListener("click", function(){
    changed.href = url.value;
    changed.textContent = title.value;
    input.style.display = "none";
  },{once : true});
}
```